# How does Scala manage to avoid racing in reactive programming?

Tags: scala, frp, reactive

As I have realized up until right now the basic idea for functional reactive programming in Scala is to define a signal that extends the `DynamicVariable` class of Scala but I could not understand something written in explanation of that class it said:

> DynamicVariables provide a binding mechanism where the current value is found through dynamic scope, but where access to the variable itself is resolved through static scope.

If I am not wrong, the dynamic scope is when a called function sees a variable from the scope of the caller program and the static scope is when it sees a variable from its own scope like the pseudo-code that follows:

```
    let x = 1
    func dynamic (y: Int) = y + x
    func static (w: Int) = y + x
    func main() = {
        let x = 2  
        dynamic (3)  //returns 5
        static (3)   //returns 4
    }
```

So the question is how is the meaning of accessing the variable itself, and if it implies writing to it, how Scala prevent racing when some functions have each a copy and want to write to the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, `dv1` is defined in the normal fashion, and is only accessible through the usual scope rules. The function `checkDv1` sees `dv1` because `dv1` is defined in its scope.

```
val dv1: DynamicVariable[Int] = new DynamicVariable(42)

def checkDv1 = println( dv1.value )
```

However, when `checkDv1` is invoked inside the `withValue()` dynamic scope, the value it gets back is different, as in it will be the newly bound value.

```
def testDv = dv1.withValue(41) {
  checkDv1
}

checkDv1
testDv
checkDv1
```

So, the output from those three function invocations should be:

```
42
41
42
```

as the dynamic scope changes.

For your other question, a `DynamicVariable` has a binding within the context of a thread. When a new thread is created, the current binding is copied to the new thread, and they have no further interaction with each other. Hence, no race conditions.

`DynamicVariable` has very little to do with reactive programming, except that its behavior is well defined in a multi-threaded environment.